A couple go to an evil old hotel
Seen this movie three years ago. Should be between 2005 and 2010. Decent american production. Good actors.
One couple go to some vacation to spend some time together. The hotel was calm, old and I think the rooms were dirty (I think the woman saw a cricket there).
The movie starts to get disturbing as they show you that the hotel has cameras everywhere inside.
Later, someone starts knocking heavily on their doors with a repeated pattern.
I remember that the husband turned on the television and saw some old tapes showing many couples getting killed by the hotel guy (and his boys). He realized that they got in the trap, and they started figuring out a solution to get out the of the hotel alive.
The boys keep on knocking on the door and they try to break in. The wife finds some tunnel underground, and she survives at the end.

Sounds like it is a movie called Vacancy (2007)  starring Luke Wilson.

Sounds like a match. It'll be much better if you add more info to your answer by adding the plot and providing a Wiki or imdb link of the movie and also try adding lines from Wikipedia which matches OP's description.

Will do from next time... thnx for the suggestion..
